# Best tool to use for creating images (png) needed for creating custom buttons

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uibutton

I am working on iMac, thinking about creating a few images for customized UIButton on iPhone app, now I wonder what would be the best tool out there that I can use. It would also be better if it's free as I am on very low budget.

Comment: try this article http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/five-tips-for-creating-stylish-uibuttons--mobile-11847 and this question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831312/how-to-create-a-glossy-with-gradient-uibutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best? Photoshop bar none. Or illustrator if you prefer vector.

Cheapest? PS trial or gimp.

Answer (score 0):

I use photoshop or fireworks :)

as for free versions i'd use gimp - http://www.gimp.org/
HTH