# how to create a glossy with gradient UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

What is the easiest way to create a button like this without having to use a .png and setting it as a background?

[image]

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons

Answer (score 2):

```
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.rem.bounds;

    gradient.cornerRadius=7.0f;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor],nil];
    gradient.opacity=0.7f;

    [self.rem.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    self.rem.layer.cornerRadius=7.0f;
    [self.rem.layer setBorderWidth:0.50f];
```

Try this and `import QuartzCore`

rem is `UIButton` outlet

i hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This common method for Gradient button.

```
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                             nil];
[btn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
```